# Delete ManyToManyField in Django from admin page and on button click

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models as follows:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Skill(models.Model):
    skill = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.skill

class Designer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)    
    date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    profile_img = models.ImageField(upload_to="gallery",null=True, blank=True)
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skill, blank=True)
    experience = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    account_type = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Designer model extends from User model and it has ManyToMany relationship with Skill model. I can add skills to designer instance from admin page but there is no delete option. How can I get the delete option on admin page? I also would like to add the delete functionality on button click. How can I add it in the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `ManyToMany` relationship field there is no `delete` functionality we need to use `remove` an instance for that or in order to clear the field value we need to use `clear` [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.remove)

say for your case

```
our_desire_skill = skills.objects.filter(skill=search_skill)
desiner_user = Designer.objects.get(user=our_desire_user)
desiner_user.skills.remove(our_desire_skill)
```

If you want to change `ManyToManyFields` from admin page need to make sure that field is like `raw_id_fields` [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields) Then you can able to update your `ManyToManyField` store value from admin site.